# iOS 7 autoresizing UITextView with AutoLayout breaks line randomly

Tags: ios, cocoa, uitextview, autolayout, textkit

I'd like to have a simple `UITextView` which automatically resizes to fit its content.

With AutoLayout this is quite straightforward: I add the `UITextView` to my view, set two contraints to anchor the `UITextView` in the top-left corner, disable scrolling and that's it.

[image: IB setup]

The expected behavior is that the green text view resize its frame each time I type in a character. But this works only partially: for some text, the text view decide that it will render it over two line, instead of just adding the new character at the end of the current line:

[image: Examples of text rendering in a UITextView]

I'm guessing this is related to the new TextKit framework, and I played with `NSLayoutManager`'s and `NSTextContainer`'s properties to try to control this behavior, but to no avail.

Note also that if I "hardcode" the width of the text view (for example with a width contraint), the characters are correctly appended at the end of the line, but then I lose the horizontal autoresizing property of the text view.

How can I indicate to the `UITextView` that I don't want it to break line?

**EDIT**: After [further testing](https://twitter.com/guillaumealgis/statuses/483718991362670592), the bug only seems to appear on 32bits archs.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I looked at the suggestion by @danhopwood below but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: TBH, I set this bug aside and moved on (I have the change to know that all my users will run 64bit devices). Hopefully it's fixed in iOS 8...

Comment: Alright. Because I'm using the UITextView as a UILabel replacement I ended up just adding a space character to the beginning and end of the string. Seems to be working decently...

Comment: adding a space at the end of the text solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently now fixed in iOS 8. (Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317)).

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack (and hoping it's fixed in iOS8) but the following stopped it from happening:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    // uber hack to stop characters from jumping to the line below
    if (textView.text.length == 1 && ![textView.text isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        NSRange cursorPosition = [textView selectedRange];
        textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", textView.text];
        textView.selectedRange = cursorPosition;
    }

    [textView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

Annoyed me for a while so hope that helps someone else :)